# Create a recursive algorithm for multiplication with no parameters

Tags: java

When calculating the rank, the number of consecutive Trails of the same type will have increasingly higher rankings. For example, one Trail of type "ice" has a ranking of 4. If there is another ice Trail immediately following it, that second one will have a ranking of 8 (2 *4). If there is a third ice Trail in that sequence, it will have a ranking of 12 (3 * 4).The overall rank of the slope is the sum of all its trails' rankings and this value must be assigned to the instance variable called ranking.

Trail is an array type. So, an example is [3, 3, 3, 3] so the overall rank should be 30. I am trying to create a recursive algorithm.

```
    public int calculateRank () {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (trail[i].equals(0)) {
                ranking = 0;
            } else if (trail[i + 1] == trail[i]) {
                ranking = calculateRank() * trail[i];
            }
        ranking += ranking;
        }
        return ranking;
    
    }
```

Trail class

```
public class Trail {
    
    private String ID;
    private String type;
    private int rank;
    
    public Trail (String ID, String type) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.type = type;
        
        if (type == "ice") {
            rank = 4;
        } else if (type == "trees") {
            rank = 3;
        } else if (type == "rocks") {
            rank = 2;
        } else if (type == "slalom") {
            rank = 1;
        } else {
            rank = 0;
        }
    }
    
    public int getRank () {
        return rank;
    }
    
    public void setRank (int newRank)  {
        this.rank = newRank;
    }
    
    public String getType () {
        return type;
    }
    
    public void setType (String newType)  {
        this.type = newType;
    }
    
    public String getID () {
        return ID;
    }
    
    public void setID (String newID)  {
        this.ID = newID;
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        String s = "";
        s += this.rank;
        return s;
    }

}
```

This is what I had written however a. I don't fully understand the code I wrote and b. It results in a compilation error.

Comment: The fact that you are relying on mutating mutable class state (`ranking`) is a big code smell.

Comment: Is the compilation error here? `trail[i].equals(0)` The fact you use *both* equals() and == is guaranteed to be incorrect. Either it's an `Integer[]` in which case use equals(), or it's a `int[]` in which case use ==

Comment: when I did ```trail[I] == 0``` it resulted in a compilation error as well. But the error actually occurs here with my current code ```calculateRank() * trail[I]``` because trail[I] is not type int

Comment: sorry I meant lowercase. I instantiated it as ```Trail[] trail = new Trail()``` I have provided that class now if it helps. sorry

Comment: If you want to multiply, you'll need to do something like `ranking = calculateRank() * trail[i].getRank();` The comparison needs to change to `== trail[i].getRank()` as well

Comment: For some reason my ranking still returns as zero. I will go through debugging to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: If the `else` block is hit, INFINITE RECURSION will occur.